# Crystal Reports If Any Record Meets Condition, Exit Formula

Tags: crystal-reports

I wish to create a formula that will read each record, and if a certain condition is met then the formula will stop reading records and return a specific label.  I have tried the following code and the correct result is displayed at the detail level but not the footer.  It appears the "exit for" isn't really working.  Thanks for your help!

Current Code (I have placed in the report footer):

```
shared stringvar label := "";  
local numbervar i;  
for i := 1 to {#Count_Records} do  
    (
    if ({report_data.return_code}[i] = "defective-exchange" 
        or {report_data.return_code}[i] = "defective") then  
            label := "Defective-Exchange Only";  
            exit for;
    );  
if label = "" then  
    label:="Pickup Credit Memo";  

label;
```

Comment: what are you exactly trying to do by placing a formula in footer? to the extent I know you can't loop all records if you place the formula in footer again it depends on which footer you are placing the formula? `group footer` or `report footer`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To eliminate data, use a record-selection formula:

```
{report_data.return_code} = "defective-exchange" or {report_data.return_code} = "defective"
```

To format data, use a formula field:

```
// {@Return Code}
if {report_data.return_code} = "defective-exchange" or {report_data.return_code} = "defective" then
  "Defective-Exchange Only"
else if {report_data.return_code} = "" then
  "Pickup Credit Memo"
else
  "something else"
```

Comment: Craig, you never cease to amaze me.  Thanks!